# Ultra Basic Question on PySpark with Kubernetes

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

After fighting with the lack of documentation and wildly misleading information out there on PySpark with Kubernetes I think I have boiled this down to one question. How do I get the driver pod that gets spun up to read my python file (not a dependency, the actual file itself)? Here's the command I'm using:

```
kubectl run --namespace apache-spark apache-spark-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
--image docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.1.2-debian-10-r44 \
-- spark-submit --master spark://10.120.112.210:30077 \
test.py
```

Here's what I get back:

```
python3: can't open file '/opt/bitnami/spark/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

OK, so how do I get this python file onto the driver pod? This vital piece of information seems to be completely missing from hundreds of articles on the subject. I have mounted volumes that the workers can see and tried that as the path. Still doesn't work. So I'm assuming it has to be on the driver pod. But how? Every example just throws in the .py file without any mention of how it gets there.

Comment: Have you considered using `configMap` and volumes?

Comment: I'll consider anything if I could find some documentation that shows me how to get the file to work. My workers already have volumes on there mounted at /sparkdata but putting the .py file in there doesn't work either.

Comment: Where is test.py file located ? Is it in your workstation or at the server from where you run kubectl command or already inside pod?

Comment: It's on the server where I run kubectl, and it's on an NFS share that the master and the workers can all see. But I can't seem to get it on the driver.

Comment: My basic understanding of this is that the driver does the spark-submit in client mode, runs the python script which hands it off to the master and the workers for processing. That could be flawed logic for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mounting any volume to the pod, so even if the file is present in the NFS mount, it won't be visible from within the pod. You must mount it.  In the following command, you are creating a pod but not attaching any volume to it.

```
kubectl run --namespace apache-spark apache-spark-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
--image docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.1.2-debian-10-r44 \
-- spark-submit --master spark://10.120.112.210:30077 \
test.py
```

If you wish to use `NFS` volume, you need to use the right PVC or hostPath to the NFS mount. **TLDR, Mount the volume.**

**Alternatively**:
You can refer to this example if you wish to use `configMap` and volumes to make a local file available inside the pod.  In this example, I have created `info.log` file locally on the server where I run kubectl commands.

**// Create a test file in my workstation**

```
echo "This file is written in my workstation, not inside the pod" > info.log
```

**// create a `config-map` of the file:**

```
kubectl  create cm test-cm --from-file info.log
configmap/test-cm created
```

**// mount the configmap as volume, notice the volumes and volumeMounts section:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: test-pod
  name: test-pod
spec:
  nodeName: k8s-master
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: ubuntu
    name: test-pod
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
     - name: my-vol
       mountPath: /tmp
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
  - name: my-vol
    configMap:
      name: test-cm

status: {}
```

**// Test now, using the volume, I can access the `info.log` file from within the pod.**

```
kuebctl exec -it test-pod  -- bash
root@test-pod:/# cd /tmp/
root@test-pod:/tmp# ls
info.log
root@test-pod:/tmp# cat info.log
This file is written in my workstation, not inside the pod
root@test-pod:/tmp#
```

Comment: In the section above, I get that I'm not mounting anything, but how do I do it as part of the kubectl run OR the spark-submit command? There doesn't seem to be any way of mounting anything.

Comment: You can surely convert your `kubectl run ...` command into a manifest file and then do `kubectl apply -f <filename>` as shown in above example. Note that, `kubectl run` (an imperative) command does not have support to mount the volume, unlike the docker command line. @mxcolin

Comment: I'll give it a try. This is such a big lift just to get a Hello World example running. Not to mention it's not documented or mentioned anywhere in any docs. Every example I see just passes the python script and it magically seems to work for them. Appreciate your help, not sure why they make this stuff so difficult.

Comment: I am not spark expert, just providing the typical pattern of loading a file in kubernetes world. If the file is already present in the pod, this won't be needed.

Comment: I hear you, I get the Kubernetes part more than the Spark part. The docs for Spark are Wild Wild West stuff.

Comment: Managed to mount the pvc's that have the python file in there. However, now something is messed up with the arguments and I get `Error: Unrecognized option: --master spark://10.105.180.230:7077` which is bizarre as it's obviously a recognized option. Who knows what level of redirection hell is happening now.

Comment: My command and args looks like this `"command": [ "spark-submit" ],
                "args": [ "--master spark://10.105.180.230:7077", "/sparkdata/test.py" ],`

Comment: break it further like `[ "--master", "spark://10.105.180.230:7077", "/sparkdata/test.py" ],`

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that worked. Just down to problems with Spark but at least it's running.